# Can I get the body of a test file with Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I've written some tests for my library that are starting to look like really good documentation on how to use the library itself.

I was wondering if Jest has an API that would allow me to grab the body of my tests so I can generate a static site with it.

What complicates this is that I am currently using Typescript for my tests (with `ts-jest`). That means the reverse of this (write tests separately inside Markdown files, and then import them into the test body before testing) would likely be very unwieldy.

Is there a good way to do this? Or will it be messy no matter what?

Comment: There are libs that allow to embed snippets. E.g. https://github.com/zakhenry/embedme .

Comment: @EstusFlask That's exactly what I need! If you made it an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most simple form, this can be achieved in Node by replacing placeholders like `<!-- embed ./path/to/js -->` with file contents in Markdown file:

```
let readme = fs.readFileSync('./README.md', 'utf8')
.replace(/<!-- embed (.+?) -->/g, (_, filepath) => fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8'));

fs.writeFileSync('./README.md', readme, 'utf8');
```

There are third-party libraries like [embedme](https://github.com/zakhenry/embedme) that do that.

Comment: I prefer embedme because it allows for specific line-number extraction (with auto indentation correction), and it's also completely idemopotent (so I can run it many times with the same effect).